# Abstract Algebra Problem - Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image]

Attempt:

$U(40) = {1, 3, 7, 9, 11, 13, 17, 19, 21, 23, 27, 29, 31, 33, 37, 39} $

Comment: What is $U(40)$? The group of integers betwee $0$ and $40$ coprime to $40$ under multiplication modulo $40$?

Comment: This is obviously your homework. Please show us what you have attempted for each part instead of just listing the elements of $U(40)$

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

1. You got it.
2. Use Euclid's division algorithm to find integers x and y so that $7x+ 40y = 1$.
3. By Euler's theorem (or Lagrange's theorem in this case) $13^{16} \equiv 1$, so the order of $13$ is either $2,4,8$ or $16$. What is the smallest value of $n$ for which $5| 13^n - 1$ and $8|13^n - 1$?
4. If $n$ is the order of $13$, then $13x = 7 \implies x = 13^{n-1}\cdot 7$.